# normal domains on the plane

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

Let $R\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a normal domain, normal with respect to the x-axis ([the definition I'm using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#Normal_domains_on_R2))

Let $\gamma:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a rotation.

Then:

A. $\gamma(R)$ is normal with respect to the x-axis

B. $\gamma(R)$ can be normal with respect to the y-axis

C. $\gamma(R)$ is normal with respect to the x-axis or to the y-axis

D. $\gamma(R)$ can be normal with respect to the x-axis and to the y-axis even if $R$ was normal with respect to the x-axis only

---

The half-annulus is a simple example showing that A is false and B is true.

I would guess C-true and D-false, but I have no proof for my suspicions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C. The same $U$-shaped half-annulus  rotated by $\pi/4$ with respect to its center is not normal with respect to the $x$-axis and to the $y$-axis.

D. A $V$-shape is normal with respect to the $x$-axis only, but rotated to $L$-shape it becomes normal with respect to the $x$-axis and to the $y$-axis.

[image]

Comment: C is clear. But as for D, I have doubts why a $L$-shaped object should be normal with respect to the $x$-axis?

Comment: @larry01 I added a picture.

Comment: obtuse angle, yeah; thanks